# Remove white space between words in a handlebar expression

Tags: handlebars.js, removing-whitespace

I’ve a handlebar expression which is giving me a dynamic string. I want to remove the white space between letters and use it as a div id. I know I can do this using JS. But is there a way to do this within handlebar template?

{{name}} is giving me “abc xyz” and I want “abcxyz” string.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is register a helper yourself and use it in your template to replace the white-space in the string with nothing.

[Handlebars.js has a function `registerHelper(String, Function)`](http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers) which (as you see) takes a string (the name of your helper) and a function that will return the result of your helper.

For example, if we want a helper function that replaces "Facebook" with "Google" in a given string you could do something like this.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('replace', function(string) {
    return string.replace('Facebook', 'Google');
});
```

In the template we would invoke it like `{{replace "Hello, Facebook!"}}` and it would return `Hello, Google!`.

In case of a multipurpose function (what it obviously should be in this case instead of the example I gave) you would pass the string to invoke the replacement on, the string to replace and what it should be replaced with.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('replace', function(string, search, replace) {
    return string.replace(search, replace);
});
```

In the same way as we did before we would invoke it in the template using `{{replace "Hello, Facebook!" "Facebook" "Google"}}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid writing your own helpers. You can use the following module : https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers

simply install it

```
npm install --save handlebars-helpers
```

And you're good to go, you can use the following helper for your issue :

```
{{replace name " " ""}}
```

Here's another usage example :

```
{{replace "a b a b a b" "a" "z"}}
<!-- results in:  'z b z b z b' -->
```